# How to host web api with Angular solution with .NET core

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, .net-core

Using .NET Core and angular to self host UI and API

How do I set up my angular / vs solution so that I can have the running following scenario.

Navigate to localhost:4200/home i.e. in chrome 
I click a button which makes a call (in the angular code) to 'api/values' rather than 'localhost:5000/api/values'

Here are the steps I take to replicate my solution.

Within vs code terminal

```
ng new myui --routing
cd myui
ng serve ## opens the default angular project on localhoost:4200/
```

open a terminal in the directory of this project

```
dotnet new webApi  ##
```

Most of my attempts to run this by changing the settings in launchsettings.json end up with page not found errors or that the ui is currently using that port

Answer (score 0):

Angular httpclient needs the full url to reach the endpoint. I usually store the "http://localhost:5000/api/" in a global variable, soy in each service I call httpclient.get( variableName + 'values').... This way I can easily change my webapi url when I deploy or change back to localserver to debug.

Comment: I think I need to rephrase my question, I want to run the api and the angular from the same host and port how do I configure this?

Comment: In localhost and with the embedded web server in angular-cli or dotnet I think you can't.  In a hosting environment ( I use IIS ) you host then angular app in the root of IIS and .core app in a folder  ( you could also install IIS in your pc and host it there )

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, and there's out of the box support, from [this doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1), do the following from a command prompt:

```
dotnet new angular
```

Then in the ClientApp folder that's created for you do:

```
npm install
```

And once that's complete, back in your original folder do the following to build and run your app:

```
dotnet build
dotnet run
```

You'll then have a single host which will serve both your angular client and your API backend, you can hit the API with e.g.:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/sampledata/weatherforecasts
```

And you'll get the client served from any other route that doesn't match an MVC controller, e.g.:

```
http://localhost:5000
```

<s>What's happening is pretty simple, it's basically a dotnet core MVC app which serves up the angular app from it's default controller action (/home/index).</s> There's a <s>second</s> controller which has the API actions.

**Edit:**

As of the latest template the Angular files are served from SPA middleware which by default is added after MVC middleware. So you'll hit the API controller that's added as part of the template first (and any other MVC controllers you choose to add). You'll then hit the SPA middleware which simply serves up the static Angular files.

There are ways to customise this process (e.g. to serve up multiple different SPAs), you can view the source code that adds the middleware [here](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/7a0413434577274666ff72ee790b53cc71b22970/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions/SpaApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs) via a call [here](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/7a0413434577274666ff72ee790b53cc71b22970/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions/SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.cs), you could then override the file provider which gets picked up [here](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/7a0413434577274666ff72ee790b53cc71b22970/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions/StaticFiles/SpaStaticFilesExtensions.cs).